# QT application stops working

Tags: c++, qt, crash

Recently i had an idea to work on my programming skills, and try to write a simple application, like checkers. Not long since the start I've faced a problem, which is my application stops working, in a seconds after i generate a new window "settings". I've noticed that this does not happen if i comment out the lines in which i change the name of the players of the MainWindow class. SettingsWindow is a guest in MainWindow class. Here's a code.

```
#include "settingswindow.h"
#include "ui_settingswindow.h"

settingsWindow::settingsWindow(QWidget *parent, QString player1, QString player2) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::settingsWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit_P1->text()=player1;
    ui->lineEdit_P2->text()=player2;

}

settingsWindow::~settingsWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void settingsWindow::on_lineEdit_P1_editingFinished()
{
    chng->player1_Name = ui->lineEdit_P1->text(); 
}

void settingsWindow::on_lineEdit_P2_editingFinished()
{
    chng->player2_Name = ui->lineEdit_P2->text();
}
```

and the header file.

```
#ifndef SETTINGSWINDOW_H
#define SETTINGSWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mainwindow.h"
class MainWindow;

namespace Ui {
class settingsWindow;
}

class settingsWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit settingsWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    explicit settingsWindow(QWidget *parent, QString player1, QString player2);
    ~settingsWindow();

private slots:
    void on_lineEdit_P1_editingFinished();

    void on_lineEdit_P2_editingFinished();

private:
    Ui::settingsWindow *ui;
    MainWindow *chng;
};

#endif // SETTINGSWINDOW_H
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you set your "chng" variable before use? If not, you'll certainly have Segmentation fault when trying to access MainWindow class through pointer.

Comment: I managed to deal with it thank's to Oleg Olivson. I didn't set variable chng. Rookie mistake, now i'm a little ashamed. Although thank's a lot for answers!

Comment: Consider using signal/slot mechanism instead of storing pointer to main window (usually it's bad design). Also, on a side note, pass objects by constant reference instead of by value: e.g. `const QString &player1` instead of `QString player1` in your constructor. Although Qt's implicit sharing protects from creating extra copies of data, it's good to have in mind ;)

Comment: Generally speaking, *storing* dumb pointers is, well, dumb. Use `QPointer` for weak pointers to QObjects living in the same thread *only* (it's an error to use it for objects in other threads), `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr` for scope-lifetime objects, and `QSharedPointer` or `std::shared_ptr` for shared ownership objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious to me the problem without seeing the code from your main window also, but I do note that your settings window is ALSO derived from `QMainWindow`, which is probably not what you want. You probably want a modal dialog, which means it should derive from `QDialog`, or if it's a permanent resident in your main window, you may want a `QDockWidget` subclass.